# Flutter Web Image Cropping On Mobile Not Working (RepaintBoundary and package screenshot: ^2.1.0)

Tags: flutter, image, crop, flutter-web-browser

I'm working on a flutter web project and i have a page that pick and uploads Images and user can zoom in or out to crop image

**the problem is:**
Cropping images on web on desktops working properly but on web on mobile not working

i wrapped the function in button that triggers code with `try {}catch (e){}`  and added a snackbar to get any error on mobile but i got nothing
i think it stuck in this function or `RenderRepaintBoundary` doesn't work on flutter web on mobile
or not compatible or something I'm not sure

if someone can help or provide alternative solution or workaround i would be grateful

I used this package that zooms in / out and crop images `cropperx: ^1.1.1`
but its not working on mobile web then i tried
`photo_view: ^0.14.0` to zoom in/out with `screenshot: ^2.1.0` to get the cropped image
but it does't work on mobile web also

then i removed `screenshot: ^2.1.0` and wrapped my PhotoView with `RepaintBoundary` and gave it a `GlobalKey` and used it with function

```
takescrshot() async {

  RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = scr.currentContext.findRenderObject();
   var image = await boundary.toImage();
   var byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
   var pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
   print(pngBytes);

 }
```

and i get cropped image on web on desktops but mobile doesn't work

Comment: tried some more logs? for example `print(image)` and / or `print(byteData)`?

Comment: yes code just stuck if i use screenshotController.capture() or when call takescrshot()

i await for them and nothing after is being executed

Comment: thanks  @pskink i found the solution is to build running this command 
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit

Answer (score 0):

After more debugging i found the error was

```
/Assertion failed: org-dartlang-sdk:///lib engine/engine/html/scene_builder.dart:94:16_ && matrix4 ［0］== window.devicePixelRatio matrix4[5] == window.devicePixelRatio is not true
```

and i fixed it running build with

```
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit
```